# htaccess rewrite condition to exclude filetypes EXCEPT those with a specific parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that is configured to pretty much route all requests to my root index.php file, except for a specific set of file extensions (images, css, js, ect). However I need to tweak that logic a bit, where I want requests for one of those excluded file extensions to be routed to the index.php IF its contained in a specific directory (may be in a subfolder of that directory). Currently I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

What `RewriteCond` do I need in order to make sure requests for .css files ARE rewritten to index.php if they are somewhere inside the root directory of `/docs`. For instance, i would want requests `/docs/subfolder/anotherfolder/myfile.css` routed to index.php, but a request for `/assets/css/global.css` to be continue to be NOT routed to index.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `[OR]` flag to add the additional css condition (even if it fails the first condition):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docs/.*\.css$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here the `[OR]` flag logically "or"'s  the 2 conditions. So even if the requested file ends with ''css'', the second condition is checked. The example regex I gave simply says that it must start with `/docs/` and that it ends with `.css`. If that's fullfilled, the first condition doesn't need to be and the request gets routed to `index.php`.

Comment: Oneliner Regex: `^(?!.*\/+(?:docs)\/+.*?).*\/*(?:[^\/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|pdf|gif|js|s?css|ico|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur|sass))$`. I know the non-capture group around docs isn't really needed, but I added it for convenience of adding more folder exclusions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two rules. The first rule routes all CSS files somewhere below the `docs` directory through `index.php`. Everything else will be handled by the second rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^docs/.*\.css$ index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond $0 !\.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: makese sense, I just went with Jon's answer purely based on style preference. thanks for the input though! :)